# SharedPreferences as Singleton class. What is right way?

Tags: android, singleton, android-preferences

I developing an app which may often use ability to store/get some pair/value data in any app place such as an activity or it fragments. I decided use for it singleton. Is my class coded in right way?

```
public class StorageManager {

    private static StorageManager instance;
    public static final String PREF_NAME = "app_settings";
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public static StorageManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new StorageManager(context.getApplicationContext());
        return instance;
    }

    private StorageManager(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String token)
    {
        editor.putString("email", token);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getUserEmail()
    {
        return preferences.getString("email", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems correct to use.

Comment: Its perfect to use...

Comment: Seems correct, you can use this snipped.

Comment: first use and then ask if you face any problem.. @Trancer dont ask before using it...

Comment: **I'm just not sure and I doubt.** Can I use it in fragment in this way: `StorageManager.getInstance(getContext()).setUserEmail('user@mail.com');` or may be I must to create object before: `StorageManager storageManager = StorageManager.getInstance(getContext()); storageManager.setUserEmail('user@mail.com');` ?

Comment: Your implementation does not appear to be thread safe. Consider implementing your singleton [as an `enum`](https://keaplogik.blogspot.se/2013/12/the-java-enum-singleton-pattern.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Another clean way to achieve the same :)

```
    public enum AppSharedPref {
    instance;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

// setter of the property.
    public void setWeatherUpadte(int value) {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext());
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("Weather", value).apply();
    }

// getter of the property.
    public int getWeatherUpadte() {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext());
        return sharedPreferences.getInt("Weather", 0);
    }
}
```

Simply access the property with :

```
AppSharedPref.instance.getWeatherUpadte();
```

Comment: I've never used this method. But I remember once read about singletons and multithreading. And for the multithreading it seems my option does not fit. Although I can be wrong.

Comment: methods in enum are not thread-safe until you make it synchronized. so they are accessible easily in multi-threading. We are just making the instance singleton.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and Easy** way to use SharedPrefrences

```
public class User {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public String getEnroll() {
    enroll=sharedPreferences.getString("userdata","");
    return enroll;
}

public void setEnroll(String enroll) {
    this.enroll = enroll;
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userdata",enroll).commit();
}

public void remove(){
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
}

String enroll;

Context context;

public User(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("userinfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

}

**Create a user class** and call it whenever you want to save the user login session

```
edt_enroll_login=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_roll_login);
user_roll = edt_enroll_login.getText().toString().trim();

User user=new User(LOGIN.this);//pass the context to user class
user.setEnroll(user_roll);//save user session(here by enrollment number) in userinfo.xml file
```

Here i used login.java file to call user class

Just create User class object to check and remove userdata(session) -`User user=new User(yourcallingactivity.this);`

And to check if user is already login use user.getEnroll() method of user class,if user is already login then jump to home activity for user

For removing the session of user after logout use user.remove() method of user class.